# synchronisation primitives for increment

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, os161

i am a begineer studying threads,
i have a homework to solve a mutual exclusion problem with os161, to counts from 0 to 10000 by starting several threads that increment a common counter. i have no ideas how to use synchronisation primitives to improve it, please help.

```
#include <types.h>
#include <lib.h>
#include <test.h>
#include <thread.h>
#include <synch.h>

enum {
    NADDERS = 10,    /* the number of adder threads */
    NADDS   = 10000, /* the number of overall increments to perform */
};

/*
 * **********************************************************************
 * Declare the counter variable that all the adder() threads increment 
 *
 * Declaring it "volatile" instructs the compiler to always (re)read the
 * variable from memory and not optimise by removing memory references
 * and re-using the content of a register.
 */
volatile unsigned long int counter;


/*
 * Declare an array of adder counters to count per-thread
 * increments. These are used for printing statistics.
 */  
unsigned long int adder_counters[NADDERS];


/* We use a semaphore to wait for adder() threads to finish */
struct semaphore *finished;

/*
 * **********************************************************************
 * ADD YOUR OWN VARIABLES HERE AS NEEDED
 * **********************************************************************
 */

/*
 * adder()
 *
 *  Each adder thread simply keeps incrementing the counter until we
 *  hit the max value.
 *
 * **********************************************************************
 * YOU NEED TO INSERT SYNCHRONISATION PRIMITIVES APPROPRIATELY 
 * TO ENSURE COUNTING IS CORRECTLY PERFORMED.
 * **********************************************************************
 *
 * You should not re-write the existing code.
 *
 * * Only the correct number of increments are performed
 * * Ensure x+1 == x+1 
 * * Ensure that the statistics kept match the number of increments
 * * performed.
 *
 *
 */

static void adder(void * unusedpointer, unsigned long addernumber)
{
    unsigned long int a, b;
    int flag = 1;

    /*
     * Avoid unused variable warnings.
     */
    (void) unusedpointer; /* remove this line if variable is used */

    while (flag) {
        /* loop doing increments until we achieve the overall number
           of increments */

        a = counter;

        if (a < NADDS) {

            counter = counter + 1;

            b = counter;

            /* count the number of increments we perform  for statistics */
            adder_counters[addernumber]++;    

            /* check we are getting sane results */
            if (a + 1 != b) {
                kprintf("In thread %ld, %ld + 1 == %ld?\n", addernumber, a, b) ;
            }
        }
        else {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }

    /* signal the main thread we have finished and then exit */
    V(finished);

    thread_exit();
}

/*
 * math()
 *
 * This function:
 *
 * * Initialises the counter variables
 * * Creates a semaphore to wait for adder threads to complete
 * * Starts the define number of adder threads
 * * waits, prints statistics, cleans up, and exits
 */
int maths (int nargs, char ** args)
{
    int index, error;
    unsigned long int sum;

    /*
     * Avoid unused variable warnings.
     */

    (void) nargs;
    (void) args;

    /* create a semaphore to allow main thread to wait on workers */

    finished = sem_create("finished", 0);

    if (finished == NULL) {
        panic("maths: sem create failed");
    }

    /*
     * **********************************************************************
     * INSERT ANY INITIALISATION CODE YOU REQUIRE HERE
     * **********************************************************************
     */


    /*
     * Start NADDERS adder() threads.
     */


    kprintf("Starting %d adder threads\n", NADDERS);

    for (index = 0; index < NADDERS; index++) {

        error = thread_fork("adder thread", &adder, NULL, index, NULL);

        /*
         * panic() on error.
         */

        if (error) {
            panic("adder: thread_fork failed: %s\n", strerror(error));
        }
    }


    /* Wait until the adder threads complete */

    for (index = 0; index < NADDERS; index++) {
        P(finished);
    }

    kprintf("Adder threads performed %ld adds\n", counter);

    /* Print out some statistics */
    sum = 0;
    for (index = 0; index < NADDERS; index++) {
        sum += adder_counters[index];
        kprintf("Adder %d performed %ld increments.\n", 
                index, adder_counters[index]);
    }
    kprintf("The adders performed %ld increments overall\n", sum);

    /*
     * **********************************************************************
     * INSERT ANY CLEANUP CODE YOU REQUIRE HERE 
     * **********************************************************************
     */


    /* clean up the semaphore we allocated earlier */
    sem_destroy(finished);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One approach is to use *optimistic concurrency* with *Compare And Swap* or similar -- coupled with spin-locks this can avoid overhead of full mutexes/semaphores in simple cases like this. However, I do not know how these concepts work in C-land :)

Answer (score 5):

Since you are a beginner in that domain, don't use the fancy stuff. Just protect your counter by a mutex and that is it.

```
// with static linkage somewhere
pthread_mutex_t countMut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
size_t count = 0;

// in the functions
pthread_mutex_lock(&countMut);
++count;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&countMut);
```

Comment: can you provide the mutex code in the form of thread.h, instead of pthread.h, my compiler have no pthread.h, thanks you

Comment: @user688550: no sorry, I don't know a single thing about this. First, you should have added an OS specific flag if you want such. Then, since this is homework, I probably wouldn't either. These are the most basic things about threaded computation. Provide yourself with documentation, books, notes of lectures whatever.

Comment: is it a little bit conflict that you know the ways in POSIX thread, but nothing about normal thread(thread.h); thanks for your advices but you should know that most of the resouces are about theorys instead of coding mechanism...beside i need a correct initialization for mutex with thread.h, because i keep having errors using the ones in internet...

Comment: @user688550: we seem to have a different view of "normal". The systems I have are all POSIX complying, and so they all have "pthread.h" and no "thread.h" ("pthread" stands for POSIX threads). You still didn't say on which OS your are working. For all OS there is a *lot* of documentation for programming resources. Learn to use a search engine, please.

Comment: @user688550, never heard of that. So this is really a teaching OS? Ask your instructors where they hide the documentation.

Comment: http://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs350/common/os161-src-html/synch_8c-source.html

Answer (score 2):

A couple of minor things;

1. don't use an enum for those values - use defines - an enum is for *things of a similar type*, e.g. fruits, error types, etc.  Number of threads and number of increments are different.
2. volatile won't make any difference to anything - it merely instructs the compiler never to optimize reads away; but you're incrementing, so you're always going to read the variable before writing

And to the main question;

1. the easiest solution to this is an interlocked increment; the GCC instrincs offer such a function

Comment: +1 Have an example or link to interlocked increment in GCC? What about other C compilers?

Comment: You'll have to use asm with other compilers. Or you could use a mutex around modifying the variable, and then just a normal increment.

Comment: I thought the mutex used to lock certain process and wake it again later, how is it able to relate to 'modifying variables' ?do the os161 or c language have a interlocked increment function ?

Comment: @R: the MS C compiler has instrincs for this as well.

Comment: I am not sure about that, my task is to improve the code by adding locks, mutex, etc. I cannot change the whole code..

Answer (score 0):

Note that "counter = counter + 1" is not a atomic operation if counter lies in memory and marked as "volatile". So the add-by-one operation must be protected by some kind of mutex thing.

You can use os161's lock facility to protect the shared data among threads. The code may look like this:

```
// declare a global lock variable so every threads can access it
static struct lock* counter_lock;

// initialize the lock before you fork threads
counter_lock = lock_create("counter lock");

// when each thread tries to access the counter, use lock to protect it
lock_acquire(counter_lock);
counter++;
lock_release(counter_lock);

// destroy the lock after all threads are done
lock_destroy(counter_lock);
```

Of course, as a assignment, you must implement thess lock interfaces in /kern/thread/synch.c by yourself.